# Wrong FBX export

Tags: export, unity, .fbx

I made a tank model. Look at this picture:
[image]

There are three meshes:

1. M1_Abrams
2. Turret
3. Gun

M1_Abrams is root mesh and Turret is child of M1_Abrams. And Gun is child of Turret.

It seems ok in Blender, and this is my export settings:

[image]

But when imported in Unity, Gun part is missing.

[image]

But actually Gun is not missing, just transform was messed up. It's rotated and scaled down completely different in Blender.

[image]

[image]

Why this happens, and how do I fix this? Any advice will very appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still stuck in this issue, however there is another way to avoid this.

Just exporting FBX not helpful, with any parameters not work either.

I solved by exported the mesh partially, like Tank Body/Turret/Gun.

In my case, tank tracks and wheels are rigged, so I have to export Tank Body, Tank Tracks, Wheels with parented Armature together. That's one.

And export Tank Turret and Gun seperately, those are two and three.

Export them individually works fine, but I had to reassemble in Unity. It's easy, just drag those three objects to the hierachy(not scene view) together and they will be located exact spot I want, even each has different pivot points.

I hope this technic might be helpful to people who faced similar situation, however if someone find better way, please answer it here so I can accept it as answer.

This is not clear "answer", so I will not mark as answer.